# Intercept the RestTemplate by getting already created RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, interceptor, resttemplate

I have logic to intercept the RestTemplate and I am adding/registering that RestTemplate in a configuration file (*SecurityConfiguration.java*)
but I want to add that interceptor from another configuration file by getting RestTemplate object which is already registered:

```
public class TranslogRestTemplateCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        boolean isRestTemplate = false;
        try {
            if (context.getBeanFactory() != null) {
                isRestTemplate = (context.getBeanFactory().getBean(RestTemplate.class) != null);
            }
        } catch (BeansException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return isRestTemplate;
    }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    private final MyInterceptor myInterceptor;

    @Value("${com.pqr.you.rest.enabled:true}")
    private boolean transEnabled;

    @Autowired
    public RestTemplateConfig(MyInterceptor myInterceptor) {
        this.myInterceptor = myInterceptor;
    }

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    // The logic added below is not working for me
    @Bean
    @Conditional(TranslogRestTemplateCondition.class)
    public RestTemplate addInterceptor(ApplicationContext appContext) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = appContext.getBean(RestTemplate.class);
        if (transEnabled) {
            List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
            interceptors.add(myInterceptor);
            restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
        }
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Actual logic for RestTemplate, which is going to return with required interceptors, and some other values (at the time of returning this restTemplate, my interceptor also need to be add here, without over riding existing values) 
OR
**by taking the below restTempalte object and add MyInterceptor to restTemplate.**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AbcInterceptor abcRequestInterceptor(XyzService xyzService) {
        return new AbcInterceptor("abc-app", null, xyzService);
    }

    // I dont want to create bean here 
    /*@Bean
    public MyInterceptor myInterceptor() {
        return new MyInterceptor();
    }*/ 

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(AbcRequestInterceptor abcRequestInterceptor) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        interceptors.add(abcRequestInterceptor);
        //interceptors.add(myInterceptor); // I dont want to add this interceptor here
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the `@Conditional` annotation from the `addInterceptor()` method?

Comment: Reason for adding @Condition class is, if i moved that RestTemplateConfig class to other common project, then i have make sure the target application should have RestTemplate bean available

Comment: Ok, but are you sure the `@Bean` is created for you (the `addInterceptor()` method is invoked)?

Comment: No, i want to invoke that addInterceptor()

Comment: if any ideas?????? @gajos

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need in this case is a [BeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) not a `Condition` class. It will allow you to modify the bean if it exists. you can create one like below instead of the `RestTemplateConfiguration` class and the `Condition`:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplatePostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Value("${com.pqr.you.rest.enabled:true}")
    private boolean transEnabled;

    @Bean
    MyInterceptor myInterceptor() {
        return new MyInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {

        if (bean instanceof RestTemplate) { // or you can check by beanName if you like
            final RestTemplate restTemplate = (RestTemplate) bean;

            if (transEnabled) {
                List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
                interceptors.add(myInterceptor());
                restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
            }
            return restTemplate;
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Note that in your code you are trying to create another `RestTemplate` instance (named "addInterceptor"), which seems to be undesired.